# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) can't post form-data with react js on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server

`POST https://waste-alert-api.herokuapp.com/datas 500 (Internal Server Error)`

I have created a React Project where I want to upload an Image with some data. Every method works fine except the post method. For better understanding, I added React JS part as well as Node Js code.

Node Js server works fine when I tested with POSTMAN.

React JS

```
const submitPostHandler = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://waste-alert-api.herokuapp.com/datas",
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: token,
          },
        }
      );

      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

```
    const metaData = {
      "wasteType": enteredWasteType,
      "location": {
        "lat": enteredLat,
        "long": enteredLong,
      },
    };
    console.log(metaData);

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", file);
    data.append("data", metaData);

    props.submitPostHandler(data);
```

Node Js

```
router.post(
  "/datas",
  auth,
  uploadOptions.single("image"),
  async (req, res, next) => {
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) return res.status(400).send("No image in the request");

    const fileName = file.filename;
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/uploads/`;
    console.log(req.body.data);
    const newData = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
const data = new Data({
      wasteType: newData.wasteType,
      location: newData.location,
      image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,
      owner: req.user._id,
    });

    try {
      await data.save();
      res.status(201).send(data);
    } catch (e) {
      res.send({ e, error: "something is wrong" });
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: does it at least return the error message "something is wrong"?

Comment: @GrafiCode no it doesn't the response I got is this ```Response {type: "cors", url: "https://waste-alert-api.herokuapp.com/datas", redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
type: "cors"
url: "https://waste-alert-api.herokuapp.com/datas"
 ```

Comment: ah, it's a CORS error. Please, take a look at this thread, it's about ReactJS fetching and CORS errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562406/trouble-with-fetch-in-react-with-cors

Comment: I handled CORS and posted json data with no issue but when I tried Form Data the problem comes...

Comment: about PostMan, this is interesting: https://academind.com/tutorials/cross-site-resource-sharing-cors/#:~:text=Postman%20simply%20doesn't%20care,backend%20resources%20but%20that's%20all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my MERN app. My client package.json file included proxy key with Heroku created app address. But it caused 500/503 internal server errors when running app on localhost.
Firstly I followed [this](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347) solution and installed http-proxy-middleware into client folder. And secondly, in my axios.post method I changed error handling from err to err.response.data as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50950011/axios-post-request-fails-with-error-status-code-500-internal-server-error).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30054652)